# Android alphanumeric keys not received by activity or view

Tags: android

I would like to receive a notification when a number or a letter is pressed on a physical keyboard in my `Activity`. I created a simple application in Android Studio with an activity that has a single view.  Enter, delete, etc. are all received, but not the actual letters or numbers.  I do not wish to use a `TextView` or `EditText` views.  I just want to be able to see the keystrokes using a simple view.  Any help is appreciated.

Here is the code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
public static final String TAG = "My Activity";
TextView view;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    view = (View)findViewById(R.id.view);
    view.setOnKeyListener(new EditText.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onKey " + keyCode);
            return false;
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    Log.d(TAG, "KEY PRESSED " + keyCode);
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}

@Override
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
    Log.d(TAG, "DISPATCH KEY" + event.getKeyCode());
    return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
}
}
```

and the layout is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.plexistream.myapplication.MainActivity">
<View
    android:id="@+id/view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with `focus` as follows.

```
this.requestFocus();
this.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
```

Comment: I assume "this" refers to view.  I tried your code, but there is no difference.  I do get onKeyDown() and dispatchKeyEvent() called on none alphanumeric key presses.  So, I don't think focus is the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it looks like this is a problem with the emulator I am using.  NoxPlayer is not passing those keys.  I switched to BlueStacks and I do not have the problem anymore.